# What's a "good" value for the loss function of a DL model like yolo?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, loss-function, yolo

I collected ~1500 labelled data and trained with yolo v3, got a training loss of ~10, validation loss ~ 16. Obviously we can use real test data to evaluate the model performance, but I am wondering if there is a way to tell if this training loss = 10 is a "good" one? Or does it indicate I need to use more training data to see if I can push it down to 5 or even less?

Ultimately my question is, for a well-known model with a pre-defined loss function, is there a "good" standard value for the training loss?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you need to train your weights until avg loss become 0.0XXXXX. It is minimal requirement to detect object with matching anchor IOU.

**Update:28th Nov, 2018**

while training object detection model, Loss might be vary sometimes with large data set. but all you need to calculate is Mean Average Precision(MAP) which exactly gave the accuracy criteria of trained model.

```
./darknet detector map .data .cfg .weights
```

If your MAP is near to 0.1 i.e. 100%, model performing well.

Follow link to know more about MAP: 
https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/map-mean-average-precision-for-object-detection-45c121a31173

Answer (score 1):

Your validation loss is a good indicator of if the training loss can further alleviate, I mean i don't have any one-shot solutions ,you will have to tweak Hyper-parameters and check on the val test and iterate.You can also get a nice idea by looking at the loss curve, was it decreasing when you stopped training or was it flat, you can get a sense of how the training has progressed and make changes accordingly.GoodLuck

Comment: I see. So it seems that the value of loss function is not a good indicator even for a well-established algorithm. I should probably go and use the good but time-consuming labor validation on test examples. thanks!